# PHP: get largest image - performance issue

Tags: php

The below code finds all the images on a given website and returns the largest, BUT it is terribly slow. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
$largest = 0;
$images = array();

reg_match_all('/(img|src)\=(\"|\')[^\"\'\>]+/i', $html, $media);
unset($html);

$data=preg_replace('/(img|src)(\"|\'|\=\"|\=\')(.*)/i',"$3",$media[0]);
foreach($data as $imgUrl) {
$info = pathinfo($imgUrl);

if (isset($info['extension'])) {
    if (($info['extension'] == 'jpg') ||
        ($info['extension'] == 'jpeg') ||
        ($info['extension'] == 'gif') ||
        ($info['extension'] == 'png')) {

        array_push($images, $imgUrl);
        $imgUrl = $this->rel2abs($imgUrl, $this->url);
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imgUrl);
        $size = $width * $height;

        if ($size > $largest) {
            $this->image = $imgUrl;
            $largest = $size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many images are we talking about fetching here? "Terribly slow" is very relative.

Comment: Your script downloads every image, if they are big, it takes a lot of time

Comment: Wont the largest file size in bytes be the largest image? Or, is that a good enough rule of thumb?

Comment: "Terribly slow" = some time the request times out... I am mainly using this to get images from e-commerce sites, so there can be up to 50(!) images, out of which 20 are sometimes quite big.

Comment: the largest file in terms of bytes might be a good rule, even though I realized it's better to sum up width and height rather than multiplying it. reason is that i rather want an image which is 50x50 than 20x1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue as you, the problem is that getimagesize is downloading image back to server then gets it's size, so i have written my own wrapper, who only reads img meta information and returns size back.
Here: http://pastebin.com/3XuSAw0q is class. It can handle jpg, png and gif files.

Use it like:

```
$image = new Parser_Provider_Image();
$sizes = $image->getImageSize('http://../../img.jpg');
```

Comment: Slightly faster than the other things, not much though. Furthermore it sometimes gives me the wrong image size, at least for JPGs.

Comment: This issue was bugging my mind for so long. Thanks for this great answer!